# if statment not working with 3rd condition having 2 OR options

Tags: c++, if-statement

I want to get result only when all 3 conditions are fullfilled, code works good when 3rd has only one option ex "smith" but taking only 1 condition if 3rd has 2 or more ex "smith"||"Smith"

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int age;
    string name;
    string lastname;
    cout << "Podaj swoje imie" << endl;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Podaj swoje nazwisko" << endl;
    cin >> lastname;
    cout << "Wprowadz swoj wiek" << endl;
    cin >> age;
    cout << "Imie: ";
    cout << name << endl;
    cout << "Nazwisko: ";
    cout << lastname << endl;
    cout << "Wiek: ";
    cout << age << endl;
    if (age < 18)
    {
        cout << "you're too young";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "you can drink" << endl;
    }
    if ((age == 27)
            && (name == "katarzyna" || "kasia" || "Katarzyna" || "Kasia")
            && (lastname == "smith" || "Smith"))
    {
        cout << "BOOM" << endl;
        cout << "BOOM";
    }
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: `||` does not work the way you think it does. Consult your text or other reputable documentation.

Comment: Off topic: rather than testing large numbers of upper and lower case versions of the same string, convert everything to upper (or lower) case and only test that case.

Comment: Please, indent you code sensibly.

Comment: please reword your question, and consolidate your code to a more readable code snippet. It's not inherently clear from the get-go what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

`lastname == "smith" || "Smith"` doesn't do what you think it does.
It is true if `lastname == "smith"` is true, or if `"Smith"` is true.
`"Smith"` always evaluates to a non-NULL pointer, so it is always true.

You want `lastname == "smith" || lastname == "Smith"`, and similarly for the second part with `name`.

Comment: It worked but the thing I don't understand is that the second part with name is working as it should

Comment: @DanielIwański No, it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the if in this way:

```
if ((age == 27) && (name == "katarzyna" || name == "kasia" || name == "Katarzyna" || name == "Kasia") && (lastname == "smith" || lastname == "Smith")) {
```

Comment: Incomplete answer. Why would you write the code that way?

Comment: Just the way as immibis told before... you always have to repeat the variable again or use user4581301 way to lower case everything and check only one way.

Comment: @user4581301: because it will work ;-)  all joking apart: This is a way all programming languages interpret statements... it's a quite beginner thing so i explained it in my comment above.